# How to change images' paths to make my frontend build work?

Tags: html, path, gulp, frontend

[image: src folder]

I'm using Gulp as a task runner.
Here I try to use BEM methodology.

All my BEM blocks are in 'library.blocks'.

In each of my blocks there's an html file that being included into index.html (it's done by using gulp-file-include plugin).

So in button.html I type `<img src='img/228.jpg'>`.
Then we include this button.html into index.html and now we have index.html with this `<img src='img/228.jpg'>` line.

All my images after build go to /dist folder and the structure looks like this:

[image: dist folder]

At the beginning I just wanted to output all my images from `/src` just to `/dist/img`.
Then I thought about name collisions. What if we have two 228.jpg in two different blocks.
I thought it'll be okay to make structure like this: `/dist/img/blockName/228.jpg`.

What do we have now? In index.html there's the line `<img src='img/228.jpg'>`. But paths changed and now it just doesn't work. What should I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

One issue I can see is that Gulp is converting images to `webp`, so you should be referencing them in that manner in your source according to your `dist` output. For example, judging by the second file structure you noted, to access `228.webp` from `index.html`, which is the converted `228.jpg`, you would use the following:

`<img src="img/button/228.webp">`